# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY In my mcmod.info JSON file?

Tags: java, json, minecraft

This is what i recive when trying to load my mcmod.info file for my mod in minecraft. What do you think it could possibly be?

```
The mcmod.info file in naters305_Test_82635018.zip cannot be parsed as valid JSON. It will be ignored
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176) ~[ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:868) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.MetadataCollection.from(MetadataCollection.java:64) [MetadataCollection.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.discovery.JarDiscoverer.discover(JarDiscoverer.java:53) [JarDiscoverer.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.discovery.ContainerType.findMods(ContainerType.java:42) [ContainerType.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.discovery.ModCandidate.explore(ModCandidate.java:71) [ModCandidate.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.discovery.ModDiscoverer.identifyMods(ModDiscoverer.java:127) [ModDiscoverer.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.identifyMods(Loader.java:347) [Loader.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:468) [Loader.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:204) [FMLClientHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:480) [bao.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:867) [bao.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.nextString(JsonTreeReader.java:154) ~[JsonTreeReader.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:358) ~[TypeAdapters$13.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:346) ~[TypeAdapters$13.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93) ~[ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) ~[ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.class:?]
    ... 20 more
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "modid": "naters305",
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "Test of a few items blocks tools and armor.",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "mcversion": "1.7.10",
        "url": "",
        "updateUrl": "",
        "authors": [
            "Naters305"
        ],
        "credits": [],
        "logoFile": "",
        "screenshots": [],
        "parent": "",
        "dependencies": []
    }
]
```

Comment: It says right at the beginning "The mcmod.info file in naters305_Test_82635018.zip cannot be parsed as valid JSON." The next line adds more detail: "Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY"

Comment: According to JSONLint it is valid json

Comment: I did a quick google search, and the example I found has the "credits" value be a string, not an array. I think that is your issue.

Comment: FYI, just because it is valid JSON, doesn't mean it is the format that minecraft expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `mcmod.info` file, the `"credits"` section is supposed to be a string, not an array as you have it:

```
"credits": [],
```

Here is one of the entries for the [`mcmod.info` for Buildcraft](https://github.com/BuildCraft/BuildCraft/blob/6.1.x/buildcraft_resources/mcmod.info) as an example of a valid entry:

```
{
  "modid": "BuildCraft|Core",
  "name": "BuildCraft",
  "version": "4.2.2",
  "mcversion": "1.6.4",
  "description": "Extending Minecraft with pipes, auto-crafting, quarries, engines and much more!",
  "credits": "Created by SpaceToad",
  "logoFile": "/assets/buildcraft/logo.png",
  "url": "http://www.mod-buildcraft.com/",
  "updateUrl": "",
  "authors": [ "SpaceToad", "BuildCraft Team" ],
  "parent":"",
  "screenshots": [],
  "dependencies": [
     "mod_MinecraftForge"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake then because now it works. Thank You